# Insert php variable with latin characters into mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, latin

I'm pretty sure, a common problem but am looking for the best practice solution.

I have a legacy database, for which I have written a script to migrate the data.

In my script I have the following:

```
$select = $dbh->query("SELECT CollectionID, CollectionCode, Name FROM $db_local.collection");
  while ($collection_row = $select1->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $collection_id = $collection_row['CollectionID'];
    $collection_code = !empty($collection_row['CollectionCode']) ? "'{$collection_row['CollectionCode']}'" : "NULL";
    $collection_name = !empty($collection_row['Name']) ? "'{$collection_row['Name']}'" : "NULL";

    $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO $db_remote.cdrs_collectiononline (
        collection_id, 
        collection_code, 
        collection_name
        ) VALUES (
        $collection_id, 
        $collection_code, 
        $collection_name
        )");
}
```

This is all fine until I run across this row:

```
| CollectionID | CollectionCode | Name                                |
+--------------+----------------+-------------------------------------+
|         1032 | MHNG           | Muséum d'Histoire Naturelle, Genève |
```

If I do this directly in mysql (note double quotes):

```
INSERT INTO cdrs_collectiononline (collection_id, collection_code, collection_name) VALUES ('1032', 'MHNG', "Muséum d'Histoire Naturelle, Genève")
```

It works. What is the best way to deal with the possibility of these latin characters using mysql pdo?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
$collection_name = addslashes(mysql_escape_string($collection_name));
```

or :

```
$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO $db_remote.cdrs_collectiononline (
        collection_id, 
        collection_code, 
        collection_name
        ) VALUES (
        '".$collection_id."', 
        '".$collection_code."', 
        '".$collection_name."'
        )");
```

Comment: Thankyou, although `$collection_name = mysql_escape_string($collection_name);` was sufficient. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late but it can help somebody else !

It would be better to use the pdo prepare and bindParam : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php

It'll escape the character according to the type you choosed.